# How to JavaScript `onmousedown` event emulation

Tags: javascript, dom-events

How to emulate a `mousedown` event using JavaScript?
See, I have a link on a page something like this:

```
<a class="boo" target="_blank" onmousedown="function_rc()" href="http://www.siteaddress.com" tabindex="2"></a>
```

and I have to dispatch `onmousedown` event in a program way, after user makes some actions.
For an example, I tried this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showChar()
{
alert('mouse down');
}
function fake()
{
var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
evt.initMouseEvent ('mousedown', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
document.getelementbyid('my_link').dispatchEvent(evt);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a id="my_link" onmousedown="showChar()" >LLL</a>
<div id="alert" onclick="fake()">Click me!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I understand it correctly - when I click on div with `id="alert"` function start working, create a MouseEvent event type=mousedown and dispatch this event on a with id="my_link". So after the event is dispatched function `showChar()` should start;
but it doesn't happen.
Who knows why and how to solve this situation?

Comment: `getelementbyid`? Capitalisation is important in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

so, the disicion was very simple (thanx to sberry2A)

```
$("#my_link").mousedown();
```

if i use it - everything fires as it should=)
p.s.\maybe it's simple for u, but i prefer asm, and js for me - better kill myself=)